# How to show/hide a certain number of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, append

I have a problem trying to show/hide a certain number of divs. I have a dynamic div created that will print everything, but hide anything after the 5th div. Then if I click the "Load More" button, it will show all and "Show Less", only the first five divs will be displayed. I tried this but didn't work. Here's the [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/9pcp72bk/)

```
var vidThumbnail = "";
for(i = 0, i < 25, i++)
{
  vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail">child ' + i + '</div>';

    // if the child elements reaches 5 thumbnails, hide the rest
  if($('.section.thumbnail .thumb > .video-thumbnail:gt(5)'))
  {
      $('.section.thumbnail .thumb').append(vidThumbnail).hide();
  }
  else 
  {
      $('.section.thumbnail .thumb').append(vidThumbnail).slice(0,5);
  }
}

$('#loadMore').click(function() // show them all
{
    $('.section.thumbnail .thumb').show();
});

$('#showLess').click(function() // hide all up to the first 5 thumbnails
{ 
    $('.section.thumbnail .thumb > .video-thumbnail').slice(0,5);
});

<section class="section thumbnail">
    <h1>Thumbnail Divs</h1>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div id="loadMore">Load More</div>
    <div id="showLess">Show Less</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original fiddle was using comma's instead of semicolons in the for loop so the initial script was failing - Then the dom it was producing wasn't what your selectors were expecting.

Here is how I solved the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/9pcp72bk/3/

```
var vidThumbnail = "";

var hideAdditionalThumbs = function() {
    var elements = $('.section.thumbnail .thumb > .video-thumbnail');
    for (var i = 5; i < elements.length; i++) {
      $(elements[i]).hide();
    }
};

$('#loadMore').click(function() // show them all
  {
    $('.section.thumbnail .thumb .video-thumbnail').show();
  });

$('#showLess').click(hideAdditionalThumbs);

for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail">child ' + i + '</div>';

    $('.section.thumbnail .thumb').append(vidThumbnail);
        hideAdditionalThumbs()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some edits on your code and it is working now : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/hc5pL6ju/

```
var vidThumbnail = "";
for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
  vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail">child ' + i + '</div>';
  $('.section.thumbnail .thumb').append(vidThumbnail);

    // if the child elements reaches 5 thumbnails, hide the rest
  if(i>5) {
      $('.video-thumbnail').eq(i).hide();
  }
}

$('#loadMore').click(function() // show them all
{
    $('.video-thumbnail').show();
});

$('#showLess').click(function() // hide all up to the first 5 thumbnails
{ 
    for(i=5; i<25; i++){
        $('.video-thumbnail').eq(i).hide();
  }
});
```